# I am stucked at this login page

Tags: android

I connected the database and connected it but at last, I am getting stuck with this error
[image: Error message on the Phone]

Comment: Welcome to SO, please share more details of your works. Let people know what to solve. Read this before -
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably your specified host is not correct.

In the error message, the host is specified as "localhost/127.0.0.1". Both localhost and 127.0.0.1 are synonymous both times your own pc.

For example, change the specified host from "localhost/127.0.0.0.1" to "127.0.0.1" and it should work.